# Connect to a database with visual basic

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to connect an database, but it crash and it say that there are a 
Connection problem, i have tryed this code in other pc, but now does not work 
the error is:

```
There was a network or instance-specific error while trying to establish a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or is not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
```

the code is this:

```
Module Module1
'FUNZIONE PER LA CONNESSIONE AL DATABASE
Public Function Connetti(ByVal sql As String, ByVal namedset As String, ByRef dataSet As DataSet)
    Dim myConnString As String = "Persist Security Info=False;database=test;server=95.134.229.235;user id=web;pwd=fiautoppzione" 'server=Server206 'user id=utente_std;pwd=145111
    Dim myConnection As New SqlConnection(myConnString)
    Dim myInsertQuery As String = sql
    Dim myCommand As New SqlCommand(myInsertQuery)
    Dim myada As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim mydset As New DataSet(namedset)
    Dim mydbs As New BindingSource

    'IO.File.AppendAllText("C:\aggiorna.txt", sql & vbCrLf)
    myCommand.Connection = myConnection
    myada.SelectCommand = myCommand
    myada.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey
    mydset.EnforceConstraints = False
    mydset.Clear()
    myada.Fill(mydset, namedset)
    mydbs.DataSource = mydset.Tables(namedset)

    If Mid(sql, 1, 6) = "update" Then
        mydset.Clear()
        myada.Fill(mydset, namedset)
        mydbs.DataSource = mydset.Tables(namedset)
    End If
    myConnection.Open()
    dataSet = mydset
    myCommand.Connection.Close()
    Return mydbs
End Function
```

and the first part of the code:

```
Option Explicit On
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.Odbc
Imports System.Xml.Xsl
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.IO.Ports
Imports FIAppStabilimento.MySql.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Namespace MySql.Data.MySqlClient
End Namespace
```

Comment: is the port for the connection open on the given IP?

Comment: i don't know, pls help me

Comment: Basic networking. when you make a connection to an IP in your case: `server=95.134.229.235` you connect through a port for instance if you use SQL Server you connect to: `95.134.229.235:1433` but that port needs to be open. It says it can't establish a connection to your database so probably your port isn't accessible.

Comment: How do I know if it's open?

Comment: check the machine and router configuration

Comment: That's not the mistake

Comment: Like the message says: Is SQL Server configured to allow remote connections? And is SQL Server Authentication enabled?

Comment: then as @RuardvanElburg said check your server configuration

Comment: The mistake is another because another code works on the project

Comment: I just noticed the namespace, is it a SQL Server database or a MySql database?

Comment: it is SQL Server db

Comment: sorry mysql database

Comment: Since the message says SQL Server and you have a MySql database there may be something wrong with the configuration. Please post the app.config.

Answer (score 0):

For mySQL connection, you must not use the sqldataconnection.

First download MySql Connector/Net
Then add the following reference:
[MySQL.Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gURUz.jpg)

Sometimes MySql for somehow is not listed under .NET tab. Go to Browse tab, and navigate to the following path:

C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net 6.6.4\Assemblies\v2.0
or C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net 6.6.4\Assemblies\v4.0
and add MySql.Data.dll
Add the following code before Public Class Form1
[MYSQL.dll Reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhseA.jpg)

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
```

Then add the following declaration below Public Class Form1

```
Dim conn As New MySqlConnection

Public Sub connect()
    Dim DatabaseName As String = "test"
    Dim server As String = "95.134.229.235"
    Dim userName As String = "web"
    Dim password As String = "fiautoppzione"
    If Not conn Is Nothing Then conn.Close()
    conn.ConnectionString = String.Format("server={0}; user id={1}; password={2}; database={3}; pooling=false", server, userName, password, DatabaseName)
    Try
        conn.Open()

        MsgBox("Connected")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    conn.Close()
End Sub
```